# Required type: T Provided: List<T> in generic Java class

Tags: java, list, generics

So i have problems understanding the following problem with generics.

**This is small peace of my class:**

```
public class BaseFiller <T> {

private final List<T> act_Bwa;

public <T extends List<T>> Map<Integer, String> makeMapFromList() {
    List<T> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<T> list : act_Bwa) {
        res.addAll(list);
    }

    //removes all duplicates from List by DbNr
    List<T> resWithoutDuplicates = res.stream()
            .filter(distinctByProperty(intProperty))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //creates HashMap (Key = DbNr, Value = name)
    return mapListToHashMap(resWithoutDuplicates, intProperty, stringProperty);
}
```

}

**I get following errorMessage:**

Required type: T

Provided: List

respectively:
Error:(81, 37) java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to java.util.List

The error occurs in the for loop.

So what i´m doing wrong in this case? Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `for (List<T> list : act_Bwa)` - act_Bwa is not a list of lists. It should be `for (T list : act_Bwa)`, or you need to change the type of `act_Bwa`. You probably want just `res.addAll(act_Bwa)`, without the for loop.

Comment: You have a type parameter named `T` on a method in a class with a type parameter named `T`. While not illegal, it is definitely confusing, name one of them something else (or get rid of one, which I suspect is possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
public <R extends List<T>> Map<Integer, String> makeMapFromList() {
    List<R> res = new ArrayList<>();

    for (List<R> list : act_Bwa) {
        res.addAll(list);
    }

    //removes all duplicates from List by DbNr
    List<R> resWithoutDuplicates = res.stream()
            .filter(distinctByProperty(intProperty))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    //creates HashMap (Key = DbNr, Value = name)
    return mapListToHashMap(resWithoutDuplicates, intProperty, stringProperty);
}
```

Or remove `<T extends List<T>>` if you want use `T` from class.

Comment: can u tell me what this means: Contents of collection 'res' are queried, but never updated

Comment: How can this work? `act_Bwa` is a `List<T>`, not a list of `List<T>`, not to speak of an unknown subtype (`R`) of `List<T>`. The loop `for (List<R> list : act_Bwa)` doesn’t work at all. In fact, it doesn’t make any sense to add a type parameter to this method.

Comment: Нe can remove parameter from the method as I suggested

Comment: I understand.. Thanks :)